# How to find many (all?) of the blogs dealing with "X"?

Tags: blog

I wish to find all the blogs who are dealing with a topic.

For example: "restaurant reviews"

The first thing I would do is to google "restaurant review blog" and start going through the list.

The question is what other means are possible out there for tracking down these bloggers?

Answer (score 4):

Try [Google Blog Search](http://blogsearch.google.com/).

---

[Google Blog Search was discontinued in May, 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Blog_Search).